# Update entire object with DBFlow

Tags: android, dbflow

I am using DBFlow in my Android project and I would like to know if there is a way to update the entire object instead of specifying each column as shown below

```
// Native SQL wrapper
SQLite.update(Ant.class)
  .set(Ant_Table.type.eq("other"))
  .where(Ant_Table.type.is("worker"))
  .and(Ant_Table.isMale.is(true))
  .async()
  .execute(); // non-UI blocking
```

From the guide 
https://agrosner.gitbooks.io/dbflow/content/SQLiteWrapperLanguage.html

The 'Set' part of the Update supports different kinds of values:

1. ContentValues -> converts to key/value as a SQLOperator of is()/eq()
2. SQLOperator, which are grouped together as part of the SET statement.

Based on this, I tried to pass in a ContentValues into the set method

```
// Native SQL wrapper
SQLite.update(Ant.class)
  .set(contentValues)
  .where(Ant_Table.type.is("worker"))
  .and(Ant_Table.isMale.is(true))
  .async()
  .execute(); // non-UI blocking
```

and I get a compile error

```
set (com.raizlabs....SQLOperator...) in Update cannot be applied 
to (android.content.ContentValues)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call it like this:

```
SQLite.update(Ant.class)
  .set().conditionValues(contentValues)
  .where(Ant_Table.type.is("worker"))
  .and(Ant_Table.isMale.is(true))
  .async()
  .execute();
```

It's not clear from the documentation niether from the source code but it should work this way.